# Distribution of U which is the value of X or Y which is closest to zero.

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the same distribution function, $F(x)$. Let $U$ be the value of $X$ or $Y$ which is closest to zero. Find the distribution function of $U$.

I have tried letting $$\mathbb{P}(U<u)=\mathbb{P}(U<u,|x|<|y|)+\mathbb{P}(U<u,|x|>|y|)\text{,}$$but I was stuck after just this step. Feels like using the definition is the best way to solve this problem since the expression of $F(x)$ is not clear.

I also want to hear some good method to make this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say what $U$ is if $X$ and $Y$ have the same absolute value but different signs, I'll suppose these are continuous random variables with density $f$.

Then e.g. if $u > 0$

$$P(U > u) = P (-Y > X > u) + P(Y > X > u) + P(-X > Y > u) + P(X > Y > u)$$

where $$P(Y > X > u) = \int_u^\infty dx \; f(x) (1 - F(x)) = \dfrac{1}{2} - F(u) - \dfrac{F(u)^2}2$$

while
$$ P(-Y > X > u) = \int_u^\infty dx \; f(x) F(-x) $$

and similarly for the other cases.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I do not quiet understand the integrals you provided, could you give more explicit explanations? Thank you.

Comment: $$P(Y > X > u) = \int_u^\infty dx\; \int_x^\infty dy\; f(x) f(y) = \int_u^\infty dx\; f(x) (1 - F(x))$$

Comment: ... where you're integrating over the region $\{(x,y): y > x > u\}$.  Draw a picture if you don't see what the endpoints should be.

Comment: This is more clear now, really helpful and professional, which I will work hard to be like in the future.